# RPC websocket keeps skeeping transactions

Tags: transactions, nfts, websocket

Hello guys this my first ever question here.

I am currently working on NFTs market analysis project and trying to **listen to transactions** that are happening on NFTs marketplaces.
For example i am currently passing Magic Eden address to **logsSubscribe** method and receiving transactions signatures (txs) that contains Magic eden address: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#logssubscribe

The main problem is i try listen for an hour and save the transactions returned and then use the **getSignaturesForAddress** to extract all signatures that happened before the last transaction i listened to and after the first.
I found a very high number of missing transactions.
i tested it and i found these numbers.
Number of websocket extracted transactions (with logsSubscribe method):  1808

Number of RPC API extracted transactions (with getSignaturesForAddress method):  22475

PS: i am using the same commitment: "finalized"
:https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress

I just can't create precise data pipeline when i am only able to extract 8% of the total number of transactions

Comment: Were you able to figure out this ?